# How to create a branch in perforce with python and avoid the editor passing the mapping by argument

Tags: python-3.x, perforce

I want to create a new branch in perforce with python and I used: `self._p4.run("branch", name)` but, every time I used that, automatically it's open an editor to insert the mapping.

My question is if it's any way to create a new branch without open the editor and in the perfect world I can pass the mapping as a list of strings.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In P4Python you can edit specs via the `fetch_spec` and `save_spec` methods:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4script/python.p4.html#python.p4.fetch_spectype
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4script/python.p4.html#python.p4.save_spectype

which are equivalent to `p4 <spec> -o` and `p4 <spec> -i`, but they convert the spec to and from a dictionary to make it easier to manipulate.  Creating a branch spec would look something like:

```
branch = p4.fetch_branch(name)
branch["View"] = ["//depot/main/... //depot/"+name+"/..."]
p4.save_branch(branch)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the mapping yourself, and avoid the editor, you just need to use `p4 branch -i` and pass the already-filled-in form yourself.

So, for example:

1. `p4 branch -o name > branchData.txt` to generate the branch form into a temporary file
2. modify branchData.txt as you desire (e.g., to change the mappings to your desired set)
3. `p4 branch -i < branchData.txt` to load your branch data into the Perforce server and create the new branch spec in the server.

Of course, you don't really need to do step (1) if your program already knows how it wants to set up the branch spec data. Just put your desired branch spec data into a file and run `p4 branch -i` with stdin redirected to that file. Or, even, you can just feed your form data directly from your program into `p4 branch -i` since it's just reading from stdin.

Comment: It's working, but at the end I am gonna use the Sam solution with fetch and save_branch. Thank you for your help Bryan

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!